# Unable to ssh with new user in EC2 machine

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, admin

I've created an ec2 machine, and followed below steps 
https://hackernoon.com/add-new-users-to-ec2-and-give-ssh-key-access-d2abd084f30c

I'm able to create the user but while doing ssh I'm getting error

**aditya_k@3.6.10.102: Permission denied (publickey).**

Can someone help me out

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Server Fault](http://sreverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full command you are using to connect. Also, have you already connected to the instance and created the new user, and added their public key to the `authorized_keys` file?